# How can I apply custom sanitization to new usernames?

Tags: customization, sanitization, username

I have a WooCommerce module creating Wordpress usernames on my behalf. I want to make sure those usernames are sanitized according to my rules, which are stricter than the Wordpress requirements.

How can I hook / override [sanitize_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_user/) to use my custom rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sanitize_user` function has a [`sanitize_user`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1873) filter. The filter gives you $username, $raw_username, $strict from the `sanitize_user` and expects you to return $username, according to the inline documentation:

```
/**
* Filters a sanitized username string.
*
* @since 2.0.1
*
* @param string $username     Sanitized username.
* @param string $raw_username The username prior to sanitization.
* @param bool   $strict       Whether to limit the sanitization to specific characters. Default false.
*/
```

You would do something like:

```
function wpse_283736_sanitize_user_filter($username){
    // do your sanitization with $username
    return $username;
}
add_filter('sanitize_user', 'wpse_283736_sanitize_user_filter');
```

Or like this

```
function wpse_283736_sanitize_user_filter($username, $raw_username, $strict){
    // do your sanitization with $username or maybe $raw_username
    return $username; // or return $raw_username;
}
add_filter('sanitize_user', 'wpse_283736_sanitize_user_filter', 10, 3);
```

You could hook to `pre_user_login` filter, available on [`wp_insert_user`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1449) function, which is used by Woocommerce user registration process.

```
$pre_user_login = apply_filters( 'pre_user_login', $sanitized_user_login );

function wpse_283736_pre_user_login_filter($sanitized_user_login){
    // do your sanitization with $sanitized_user_login
    return $sanitized_user_login;
}
add_filter('pre_user_login', 'wpse_283736_pre_user_login_filter', 10, 3);
```

If you are not familiar with WordPress Filters, I suggest you read these references first:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/
- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/understanding-using-wordpress-hooks/
- https://pippinsplugins.com/a-quick-introduction-to-using-filters/

Hope it helps you.

Comment: This worked for me once fixing the epic function name spelling errors.

Comment: wow, thanks for pointing it out. It took almost 4 years to someone to notice and point it.  I am sorry for the epic misspellings. Shame on me.